# How to delete data with multiple parameters in Destroy function - Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am making simple crud and want to delete favourite list table's columns if `user_id` and `hymn_id` matches from `favourite_list` table

here is my delete route:

```
Route::resource('fav_hymns', 'Api\favouriteController');
Route::delete('fav_hymns/{user_id}/{hymn_id}/', 'Api\favouriteController@destroy');
```

and my 'destroy' function in resource favouriteController

```
public function destroy($user_id,$hymn_id)
{

    $favourite_list = favourite_list::where('user_id','=',$user_id, 'AND', 'hymn_id', '=', $hymn_id)->delete();


    if (!$favourite_list) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Error: List not found'
        ], 400);
    }

    if ($favourite_list) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'List could not be deleted'
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

but the problem is, it's deleting all the columns if `$user_id` matches and  `$hymn_id` (in route) doesn't even exist and doesn't even match, it is deleting all the columns.

Help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete `where()` condition is not correct here. You should try like.

```
try{

 favourite_list::where('user_id', $user_id)
                            ->where('hymn_id', $hymn_id)
                            ->delete();

} catch(\Exception $e){
    return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'List could not be deleted'
    ], 500);
}


 return response()->json([
     'success' => true
 ]);
```

Each conditions should be wrap under different `where()`. If you would like the SQL format... try using `whereRaw()`.

Comment: @NoumanNazir it seems you marked the different solution... make sure you are correct. As with that... suppose if you have 5000 records... it could loop over each record and delete one by one. So It would not be the good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Do sth like this

```
public function destroy($user_id,$hymn_id)
{

    $favourite_lists =favourite_list::where('user_id', $user_id)
                            ->where('hymn_id', $hymn_id)->get();

    foreach($favourite_lists as $favourite_list)
    {
      $favourite_list->delete();
    }
    return response()->json("records deleted",200);
}
```